# What are the tscparams files for?

Tags: typescript

When I use the [a DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) in my Typescript project I notice that sometimes there is a file included with the tscparams extension.

What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used to customise the parameters passed to the compiler. This is specific to our testing framework. See : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/wiki/How-to-contribute#tests